# Best way to send event from AngularJS parent component to Angular 7 child component? (ngUpgrade)

Tags: angular-upgrade

I have an AngularJS (1.7) app which is being migrated to Angular 7, using ngUpgrade. So the AngularJS and Angular frameworks are running at the same time, new components are written in Angular, and sometimes these modern Angular components are used inside of legacy AngularJS components.

In my case, the parent component needs to communicate with the child component in certain circumstances.

The [ngUpgrade docs](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) clearly show how to pass data and propagate events from the child Angular component to the parent AngularJS component:

```
<legacy-angularjs-component>
    <div>{{ $legacyCtrl.whatever }}</div>
    <modern-angular-child-component
         [data]="$ctrl.initialDataForChildComponent"
         (changed)="$ctrl.onChildComponentChanged($event)"
    >
    </modern-angular-child-component>
</legacy-angularjs-component>
```

To make that work, you just need to add a couple properties to the Angular child component: `@Input() data;` for the initial data, and `@Output() changed = new EventEmitter<WhateverThing>();` that can then be used to propagate events to the parent component by doing `this.changed.emit(this.whateverThing)`.

That all works, but what about propagating events from the parent to the child? I know how to do this in Angular, e.g. with `@ViewChild` or using observables, but those mechanisms are not available in my app's AngularJS environment. So the parent component cannot use them.

Two approaches I have tried that do work are:

1. Creating a separate service, which both components share.
2. Pass a reference to the parent controller into the child controller like this:

```
<legacy-angularjs-component>
    <div>{{ $legacyCtrl.whatever }}</div>
    <modern-angular-child-component
        [observe]="$ctrl.registerObserver",
    >
    </modern-angular-child-component>
</legacy-angularjs-component>
```

...and then having the child component invoke this `observe` function:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    if (this.observe) {
      // Pass reference to child component to the
      // parent, so parent can directly send it messages.
      this.observe(this);
    }
  }
```

This way, the parent has a direct reference to the child once the components are set up. The child implements some TypeScript interface that defines all the methods of the child that the parent can invoke to inform the child of events.

Both of those do work, but they both strike me as fairly kludgey and a lot of rigamarole to have to do for something as simple as sending an event to a child component.

Since this is easy to do in both AngularJS and Angular,  I wondered if I might be missing an easier/simpler way to do the same thing in the context of `ngUpgrade`, where the parent is AngularJS and the child is Angular 7.

Or is my second approach a reasonable way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Eazy-E once said, "Ask, and ye shall immediately think of a simpler answer, right after you post the question in public."

A better solution than either of my first two mentioned above is to simply use regular Angular one-way bindings and use the `OnChanges` mechanism provided by Angular.

```
<legacy-angularjs-component>
    <div>{{ $legacyCtrl.whatever }}</div>
    <modern-angular-child-component
         [observed]="$ctrl.valueThatChildIsObserving"
    >
    </modern-angular-child-component>
</legacy-angularjs-component>
```

Then, in the child component:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

export class MyChildCompoennt implements OnChanges {

  @Input() observed: SomeWhateverObject;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    console.log(changes);
    // Inspect changes (it contains old and new values
    // for `observed` object. That object could be a string
    // or something more complicated with multiple properties.\
  }

}
```

This way, when the parent component wants to tell the child to do something, it can just do `this.valueThatChildIsObserving = someWhatever;`.

Angular will handle invoking the child component`ngOnChanges()`, passing it a structure containing the old and new value of the property.

You have to implement the child component so that it can inspect the changed value and execute the correct action, but that is pretty simple and avoids having to have the parent/child share references to each other.

I think this is a reasonably simple way to implement "propagate some kind of event from parent component to child component" in a hybrid AngularJS/Angular app using `ngUpgrade`.